# Why is $d\mathbf{a}$ a vector when doing surface integrals?

Tags: integration, vectors, vector-analysis, surfaces, surface-integrals

I'm just learning about surface integrals, and I'm doing a problem where I'm supposed to calculate the surface integral of some vector function $\mathbf{v}$ over five sides of a cube. For the first side, $x = 1$, so $dx = 0$. I get this. But then the book says, "so $d\mathbf{a} = dydz\mathbf{\hat{x}}$". This I can't seem two wrap my head around. I know that $d\mathbf{a}$ is supposed to be an infinitesimal area, so why is it a vector? Shouldn't it be a scalar?

Comment: It's an infinitesimal oriented area. Really, it ought to be a bivector $dy\,dz\,\mathbb{\hat y}\mathbb{\hat z}$, but we often use the Hodge dual to make everything vectors and scalars. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bivector

Comment: Can I think of it like this? if my vector function $\mathbf{v}$ is a velocity function for some fluid that is flowing out of the cube, then the fluid has some direction, e.g for the sides of the cube that lie in the $xz$ plane, the direction is in the $y$ direction, so I should actually calculate $\iint \mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} dA$, where $dA$ is now a scalar quantity, for example $dA = dxdy$ when $\mathbf{\hat{n}}$ is in the $z$ direction, and $\mathbf{\hat{n}}$ gives the direction of flow? (the integals are supposed to be closed, but it seems \oiint doesn't work here.)

Comment: It depends whether you want to integrate a scalar function or a vector field over the surface. In the latter case, you are computing flux and you need to know the unit normal vector on your tiny piece of surface. (By the way, you don't need closed surfaces for this, so you don't need \oiint.)

Comment: Yeah, I'm talking about a vector field like $2xz\mathbf{\hat{x}} + (x+2)\mathbf{\hat{y}} + y(z^2 - 3)\mathbf{\hat{z}}$ for example.Yes, the unit normal vector is what I meant by direction of fluid flow ($\mathbf{\hat{n}}$). I suppose i could have articulated myself more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think everything works out if we just say $\mathbf{\hat{n}}$ is the unit normal vector to the surface, and then $dA$ is a scalar quantity, e.g. $dA = dxdy$ when $\mathbf{\hat{n}}$ is in the $z$ direction.